# Poltergeist Timeout Error when Visiting login page on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-12.04, phantomjs, poltergeist

Given `Ubuntu 12.04` , `Poltergeist 0.7.0` , `PhantomJS 1.6.5` and a spec  ( that passes using just plain old `capybara webkit` or `selenium` ), I get the following error when trying to visit a page:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError:
   Timed out waiting for response to {
     "args":["http://127.0.0.1:41706/login",{}],
     "name":"visit"
   }
```

Same command also passes locally on Mac 10.7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it's timing out because you are trying to access a port that is not open on the machine.  Have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: Hi there @FilmJ , no restrictions on this port, this works fine in normal rspec / cucumber / capbyara specs, but fails with poltergeist.  I just gave up on poltergiest and settled for running with rspec / capybara-webkit.  Thanks for replying though.

Comment: @kikuchiyo did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: @austinfromboston, no, I gave up on poltergeist a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have Google Analytics in your page?
I found wrapping the analytics code in something like `<% unless Rails.env.test? %>` managed to stop the page from timing out.

Comment: Awesome!  Yes I think we do.  I'll give this a try today :)

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I checked and we are indeed omitting the google analytics code in test environment.

Answer (score 2):

**Using this in Capybara.rb file solved my issue:**

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
options = { js_errors: false, timeout: 180, phantomjs_logger: StringIO.new, logger: nil, phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'] }

Capybara.register_driver(:poltergeist) do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new app, options
end
```